# Unable to share link to WhatsApp Web with get method

Tags: php, html, text, send, whatsapp

I've been trying to send a link through either WhatsApp Web or WhatsApp Mobile from my website. WhatsApp Mobile is working fine by sending the full url but not working with the web version.

Here is how my code looked like :

```
<a target="_blank" href="https://web.whatsapp.com/send?text=https://www.myexampledomain.com/redirect?referral=4a66c7b62460b" data-action="share/whatsapp/share"> Whatsapp Web </a>
```

As you can see there I have set a GET data in my url `referral=4a66c7b62460b`. I am able to send the url through WhatsApp Web, but when displayed in the text input message to send, the GET data has been removed for some reason.

Instead of sending this url : `https://www.myexampledomain.com/redirect?referral=4a66c7b62460b`

It is sending this : `https://www.myexampledomain.com/redirect?referral`

Comment: Try [urlencode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php)'ing the link.

Comment: @LawrenceCherone tried that and still the same.

Comment: @LawrenceCherone Oh I made a mistake in my coding when trying the `urlencode()` . It's working now. Thanks for the superb solution!